# Updating a WordPress site and database from Localhost to third-party host using FTP

Tags: wordpress

Following this tutorial, https://medium.com/pen-bold-kiln-press/making-a-wordpress-website-live-from-localhost-198026ccd1c0 I've:

1.) Export localhost database from phpmyadmin

2.) Upload localhost files to live site through FTP

3.) Create a new MySQL database for the new site

4.) Import the localhost database to the live database

5.) Change the site URL and home in the database

6.) Configure wp.config on the live site

I am used to making webpages without Wordpress (custom html + css) and then just uploading the files to public.html....

My question is: If/when I make changes to the site on localhost, do I have to export the database and create a new MySQL database on the webhost each time or can I simply upload the wordpress files to publichtml each time to see my changes.

Do I only need to export the database once, on the initial push live?

(I make alot of changes usually)

Answer (score 0):

If you change only theme file html+css or PHP to change view or print something, so not. You need to upload only changed files, without database.

If you make changes thru admin panel, like install plugins or change some option on a site then you need to update DB.

Also if you create some PHP code that change database like create something( new DB tables, change info inside tables, etc).

Comment: Do you need to delete the database each time and create a new one? or is there any way you can import database changes?

Comment: @West It will be more clearer to delete all tables in the database and made an import